# How can free switch initiate a conference by a scheduled time

Tags: sip, freeswitch

I've tried to set up conference call using asterisk & free switch as well where my SIP soft phone is XLite. I'm able to do conference using both asterisk & free switch with XLite. Now i'm trying the reverse way that instead of endpoints start the conference,let free switch it self to start a conference at a scheduled time.
As per the research i've done I've wrote a dialplan file to make it work out.

These are some  application & API which is useful for my idea,
minute-of-day --> for scheduling a task at a perticular time
conference_set_auto_outcall --> for calling endpoints to join a conference

I've added the below to default.xml of dialplan

```
    <extension name = "scheduling" >
           <! -- condition is every day at 10 am start conference-->
              <condition minute-of-day= "600">
              <!-- do conference as action -->    
    <!--condition field="destination_number" expression="^(3000)$"-->    
 <action application="answer"/>
 <action application="set" data="conference_auto_outcall_timeout=5"/>
 <action application="set" data="conference_auto_outcall_flags=none"/>
 <action application="set"
 data="conference_auto_outcall_caller_id_name=$${effective_caller_id_name}"/>
 <action application="set"
 data="conference_auto_outcall_caller_id_number=$${effective_caller_id_number}"/>
 <action application="set" data="conference_auto_outcall_profile=default"/>
 <!-- called to my detsination -->
 <action application="conference_set_auto_outcall" data="user/1001@$${domain}"/>
 <action application="conference_set_auto_outcall" data="user/1002@$${domain}"/>
 <action application="conference_set_auto_outcall" data="user/1003@$${domain}"/>
 <action application="conference" data="$1@default"/>
 </condition>
 </extension>
```

I'm not able to find out why it's not working ?
atleast some actions it should perform at the scheduled time.
After my changes i've reloaded the xml as well in the below way
start fc_cli & then run reloadxml command

Answer (score 0):

The dialplan extension, and therefore the time-routing condition, will not run on it's own. It has to be called, so unless there is a call transversing the dialplan and triggering that 'scheduling' extension, it will not work. Probably the best way to go about this would be to use the `originate` command to call the users and then bridge them into the conference:

`fs_cli -x "originate sofia/internal/1000@$${domain} &conference($1@default)"`
`fs_cli -x "originate sofia/internal/1001@$${domain} &conference($1@default)"`
`fs_cli -x "originate sofia/internal/1002@$${domain} &conference($1@default)"`

You can put this on a cron to run on the time you want and it should accomplish what you are trying to do above.